# How do I print my logical volume group UUID to file?

Tags: terminal, core-storage, uuid

I'm in the process of trying to automate getting the LVGUUID and printing it as a string to a text file, or better piping it in terminal to other commands. All I can do right now is `diskutil coreStorage list` and then copy/paste the UUID as needed. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What's the real issue here? The `df .` command will get you the raw filesystem device for the current directory. (disk1s1 for me at present) and `diskutil info disk1s1` gets you the details about that filesystem. `system_profiler SPStorageDataType | grep "LVG UUID"` also works to dump just the existing UUID the system knows about right now.  It's not clear why you'll want to know the enclosing group - but perhaps the existing answer is exactly what you want?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is break Core Storage, as the Macs in question are being imaged for public use. Therefore I'm running a script from a removable hard drive and it just saves me a couple steps if I can auto-populate the command rather than copying and pasting.

Comment: Excellent use case @christian - imaging is hard work. Check this guy for scripts, workflows, and more - https://derflounder.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is just example *code* as I only have one Core Storage Volume to test against, however, if there's more then one, the `awk` command could be modified to accommodate accordingly. Although without the output of multiple Core Storage Volumes, I cannot give an example.

If it's the `Logical Volume Group UUID`, you can user the following example:

```
$ lvguuid="$(diskutil coreStorage list | awk '/Logical Volume Group/{print $5}')"
$ echo "$lvguuid"
696AD841-1F53-4D33-9496-3E36D33AB270
$
```

In the `awk` *command*, you can substitute `Logical Volume Group` with `Physical Volume`, `Logical Volume Family` and  change `$5` as appropriate. Based on the order of the search string shown in this line, it will be `$5`, `$4`, `$5`.

For `Logical Volume`, you'll need to use a `regex`, as in the following example:

```
lvuuid="$(diskutil coreStorage list | awk '/Logical Volume [A-F0-9]{8}-/{print $4}')"
```

Understanding the `regex`:

- `Logical Volume [A-F0-9]{8}-`

  - `Logical Volume` matches the characters `Logical Volume` literally (case sensitive).
- `[A-F0-9]{8}` - Match a single character present in the list below.

  - `{8}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 8 times.
  - `A-F` a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `F` (index 70) (case sensitive).
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` (index 48) and `9` (index 57) (case sensitive).
  - `-` matches the character `-` literally (case sensitive).

So, in my example `awk` matches `Logical Volume 38712F52-` and returns:

```
38712F52-5967-4A49-87D6-C66D4B199F28
```

---

The above examples set a *variable* that can be called from the *command line* or *script*, however, if you what the output to a *file*, then use the following example:

```
diskutil coreStorage list | awk '/Logical Volume Group/{print $5}' > /path/to/filename
```

---

On my system here's the output of the `diskutil coreStorage list` *command* on an encrypted USB Flash Drive:

```
$ diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 696AD841-1F53-4D33-9496-3E36D33AB270
    =========================================================
    Name:         Encrypted
    Status:       Online
    Size:         15661490176 B (15.7 GB)
    Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume E0E76F6B-A4E2-466D-B8E5-D5977ECD0522
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk3s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     15661490176 B (15.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family EAF4984B-94C8-49B6-BCC6-76A8724E04D2
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            Yes
        Passphrase Required:     Yes
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 38712F52-5967-4A49-87D6-C66D4B199F28
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:               disk4
            Status:             Online
            Size (Total):       15325941760 B (15.3 GB)
            Size (Converted):   -none-
            Revertible:         Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:            Encrypted
            Volume Name:        Encrypted
            Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
$
```

Comment: Also - APFS containers likely won't follow along the core storage path with LVG UUID - so I'm asking the OP to clarify what they actually want to do. This is likely an X Y problem - a useful and interesting one, but still XY.